# How to extract data from table using Beautifulsoup, with no text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to extract the leaderboard on https://fortnitetracker.com/events/epicgames_S11_PlatformCup_PC_NAE.

However the data inside the table is not extractable as 'text' elements. Do not know how to extract player names...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://fortnitetracker.com/events/epicgames_S11_PlatformCup_PC_NAE"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
table_needed = soup.find_all('table',attrs={'class':'trn-table'})
table_needed=table_needed[0]

for i in table_needed:
    print(i.find('div'))
```

This gives me the output. What can i do from here?
'{{ getPlayerNameList(entry.teamAccountIds, 4) }}'

I see theres a getPlayerNameList...

Comment: Can you provide any code sample, what have you tried and clear result you want to get?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I tried providing a code sample right now...

Answer (score 0):

the player names are dynamically injected into the table with javascript(vue) so I don't think that you can scrape it with just beautifulsoup, i would suggest you try tools like selenium.